# VPN on a Virtual Machine in VirtualBox

Tags: vpn

I am running a VPN connection through Cisco AnyConnect, but I can't get it working on my Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox, I tried bridging connections, but then everything failed. Any hints/tips?

Comment: Since a VPN uses a virtual network adapter, your bridging is going to the wrong adapter, so the host is logically a member of the remote network, while the guest is still a member of the local network. I'm not certian there is a good solution to this problem, other than to handle the VPN connection upstream of the host box, at the router or a proxy.

Comment: I can connect to an OpenVPN server from a VM in VirtualBox. Host is connected via ethernet, guest is in `Bridge Adapter` configuration, OpenVPN is in `routed` mode. Host is Debian, guest is Kali. Plese try to get `Bridge Adapter` configuration for your guest to work, then report which errors you are finding.

Comment: @op, please clarify, are you trying to connect from a Guest, or are you connecting from the Host? My comment assumes you mean the host is connecting to the report network, but that you want the guests connection to use the VPN as well. Perhaps that was an unwarrented assumption.